# MySQL how to update aggregated table (based on another table) automatically?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, innodb, mysql-python

I have a table (table1) in a MySQL database with data similar to this:

| Category | total_sold | revenue | profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fruit | 32 | 200 | 150 |
| veggies | 12 | 50 | 23 |
| chips | 23 | 170 | 110 |
| fruit | 43 | 300 | 180 |
| chips | 5 | 25 | 15 |

New data is inserted into the table regularly through a python script using sqlalchemy (appends csv files to the mysql table using Pandas).

I want to create an aggregated table (table2) based on category using a query, and I want the aggregation to update whenever I add new records to the table1.

For example after executing the query:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
SELECT Category, AVG(total_sold) avg_sold, AVG(revenue) avg_revenue, AVG(profit) avg_profit
FROM table1
GROUP BY 1
```

I get table2 as:

| Category | avg_sold | avg_revenue | avg_profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fruit | 37.5 | 250 | 165 |
| veggies | 12 | 50 | 23 |
| chips | 14 | 97.5 | 62.5 |

Now if I insert several new records to table1, how can I make table2 update automatically? (recalculate all aggregations based on all table1 records including the newly added ones)

I read about creating a trigger, but I'm not sure how to execute it or if it would work in a case like this.

I Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Instead of creating a table you should create a View. Then you can select from that View and always have up to date results.

Comment: @forpas I'm not familiar with views but I will take a look online and try it. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support "materialized views".  You have to do the aggregation yourself.  Build a separate [*Summary Table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) and keep it updated.  A simple IODKU is one way to do that maintenance; the link discusses other, such as a nightly batch update of the day's data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think a view will do the trick for now, I just wasn't familiar with views.